# Inserting int value in database using scrappy by skipping apostrophes

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I made a crawler for a website using a scrappy. Now o want to insert the scraped prices in MYSQL database using scrappy pipeline and i couldn't deal with the apostrophe's. I have every i could find on the internet.

I have every i could find on the internet.

```py
import mysql.connector


class EloPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            database='elodata'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        pass

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS elo_tb""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table elo_tb(
        product_name text,
        new_price int,
        old_price int
        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)

        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into elo_tb values(%s, %s, %s)""", (
            item['product_name'][0],
            ''.join([s.encode("utf-8") for s in item["_new_price"][0]]),
            ''.join([s.encode("utf-8") for s in item["_old_price"][0]])
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

This is the code for `my pipeline.py`. I also tried to use the `.join` but it gives a new error: `"TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found"`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the type of the item, if it's `string` type use `''.join()`

```
>>> ''.join(['line1', 'line2'])
'line1line2'
```

elif  `byte` type use `b''.join()`

```
>>> b''.join([b'line1', b'line2'])
b'line1line2'
```